# Reset Simulation in Gazebo fortress via API

Tags: gazebo, ignition-fortress

I'm building a RL training environment using Gazebo Fortress and ROS2 Humble. So far I've been creating a new Server instance in between episodes, but it seems like this is not always resetting my simulation (perhaps because I'm calling it via pybind and python is not garbage collecting when I create the new one?).

Is there a way for me to keep the same server instance but reset the world via the C++ API?

Answer (score 2):

Gazebo Garden has a [Reset API](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/reset_simulation.html). You can use gz-transport to send a reset command, but additionally, systems can implement the `ISystemInterface` to do something specific when a reset is requested, such as slightly changing the world for a new episode of RL training. [Here's](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim7/examples/plugin/reset_plugin) an example.